# Execute select query (longer than 4000 chars) on oracle from java using hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, oracle11g, clob

I have a long select query, oracle database (11g) and hibernate 3.
On java side I have query:

```
String query = "Select {some different columns} from {some tables} where param1='{some string longer than 4000 chars}' and param2= ...";
```

How can I execute it and get the results using hibernate session? 
If I just use createSQLQuery, I get:

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01704: string literal too long
```

And I would prefer solution, that doesn't use session.connection() because it's deprecated.

Thanks!

Comment: Exactly how long is the parameter value that you're checking?

Comment: @DavidWallace 600000 characters is a max. But most of them less than 40000 chars.

Comment: Then I suggest a redesign.  You can't possibly want to have your database EITHER indexing a column that can reach 600k characters, OR comparing multiple rows to a 600k string.  Oracle's restriction on the length of string literals is saving you from yourself.

Comment: May I suggest adding a column to your table which stores some kind of hashed version of `param1`?

Comment: @DavidWallace in fact this query looks smth like this
select * from lalal where function_that_takes_clob(long_clob) = 'TRUE'

I think I have the solution of doing this query using temp table (SQLQuery q = session.createSQLQuery(query);       q.setParameter("long_clob", longClobValue); ) but I wanted to do it in one query.
long_clob is wkt text. So it can be really long.

Comment: Your temp table solution probably won't work, because you'll still be sending your really long literal to Oracle.  I don't understand though - in `function_that_takes_clob(long_clob)`, where does your literal fit in?  If it's the actual `long_clob`, can you just rewrite your function in Java, and evaluate it before you run the query?

Comment: @DavidWallace No, It has to be on oracle side.
I thought there should be a way to execute such kinds of query. Using some kind of "clob streaming".
Thanks anyway for ideas!

Comment: There might be.  The `PreparedStatement` class has `setAsciiStream` and `setCharacterStream` methods that you might be able to use.  But I don't know whether Oracle will let you use these in a where clause.  Worth a try I guess.  But I honestly think that if you can redesign your database to avoid this situation, you should think about doing so.